# What can we conclude about 2 discrete signal which agrees on one period

Tags: signal-processing

Let \$x[n]\$ be a discrete signal. Now let \$ \tilde{x}[n] \$ be a periodic discrete signal, which agrees with \$x[n]\$ only on one period.

The period of \$\tilde{x}[n]\$ is \$5\$   and according to my exercise book, one can conclude that \$ x[n] \$ is non-zero only for \$ 5 \$ indices \$ n_1,n_2,...n_5\$

I really cannot see how is this true. If anyone can explain it, I would be greatful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know *anything* else about $x[n]$? because the way you state it, you just literally state what your book says: there's five values you know, namely those who are the same between $\tilde x$ and $x$; you're not even stating $\tilde x$ is non-zero, so not even the conclusion that $x$ would need to be non-zero for these values is correct.

Comment: if x~[n] is non-zero (which doesn't appear to be stated), then those 5 corresponding samples of x[n] are non-zero. That's all that can be concluded. Maybe moving the word 'only' about in the sentence is required, and it applies to concluded rather than non-zero.

Comment: @MarcusMüller You right. The conclusion of the book is that the value dosent have to be zero there. The original given details are that \$x[n]\$ agrees with periodic real signal only on one period, and the question is "What can we say about \$x[n]\$? The answer in the book states that there can only be \$5\$ values where the signal is nonzero

Comment: does that make any sense?

Comment: no, because as Neil says, all we can say is that 5 values of x are the same as ~x, that's it. Nothing about zero-ness can be inferred.

Comment: One **cannot** conclude that \$x[n]\$ is non zero for \$n_1 \dots n_5\$. e.g. \$\tilde{x}[n] = {0,2,3,4,5,0,2,3,4,5,0,2,3,4,5,\dots}\$. x[1] is 0 in this example even though \$\tilde{x}[n]\$ is periodic.

Comment: If it is an exercise book, this question may depend on information given in previous questions. Questions in exercise books are often built upon previous question and examples in the text book. So there may be missing information in the question.